# Get JSON Element in Swift 3

Tags: json, swift3

Please excuse me if this is a simple question, but I am stuck. I have tried to read everything I can to work it out myself.

I am trying to extract a URL from JSON data, I get the JSON data fine and I can print it to the console, however I can't work out how to access the URL for the audio file.

This is the code I use to get the JSON:

```
 let session = URLSession.shared
    _ = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        if let response = response,
            let data = data,
            let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) {

            if let dictionary = jsonData as? [String: Any] {
                if let prounce = dictionary["pronunciations"] as? [String: Any]{
                    if let audioPath = prounce["audioFile"] as? String {
                        print(audioPath)
                    }

                }
            }

            print(response)
            print(jsonData)
        } else {
            print(error)
            print(NSString.init(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
        }
    }).resume()
```

The output I get is:

```
metadata =     {
    provider = "Oxford University Press";
};
results =     (
            {
        id = maladroit;
        language = en;
        lexicalEntries =             (
                            {
                entries =                     (
                                            {
                        etymologies =                             (
                            "late 17th century: French"
                        );
                        grammaticalFeatures =                             (
                                                            {
                                text = Positive;
                                type = Degree;
                            }
                        );
                        senses =                             (
                                                            {
                                definitions =                                     (
                                    "inefficient or inept; clumsy:"
                                );
                                examples =                                     (
                                                                            {
                                        text = "both men are unhappy about the maladroit way the matter has been handled";
                                    }
                                );
                                id = "m_en_gb0494140.001";
                            }
                        );
                    }
                );
                language = en;
                lexicalCategory = Adjective;
                pronunciations =                     (
                                            {
                        audioFile = "http://audio.oxforddictionaries.com/en/mp3/maladroit_gb_1.mp3";
                        dialects =                             (
                            "British English"
                        );
                        phoneticNotation = IPA;
                        phoneticSpelling = "\U02ccmal\U0259\U02c8dr\U0254\U026at";
                    }
                );
                text = maladroit;
            }
        );
        type = headword;
        word = maladroit;
    }
);
```

}

I want to get the URL called `audioFile` in the pronunciations. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: the upper statement is presented upon using which print statement?

Comment: Show the actual JSON response instead of showing console output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my guess is right, your output shown above lacks opening brace `{` at the top of the output.

(I'm also assuming the output is taken from your `print(jsonData)`.)

Your `jsonData` is a Dictionary containing two values:

- A dictionary value for "metadata"
- An array value for "results"

So, you cannot retrieve a value for "pronunciations" directly from `jsonData` (or `dictionary`).

You may need to:

- Retrieve the value for "results" from `jsonData`, it's an Array
- Choose one element from the "results", it's a Dictionary
- Retrieve the value for "lexicalEntries" from the result, it's an Array
- Choose one element from the "lexicalEntries", it's a Dictionary
- Retrieve the value for "pronunciations" from the lexicalEntry, it's an Array
- Choose one element from the "pronunciations", it's a Dictionary

Here, you can access the values in each pronunciation Dictionary. In code, you need to do something like this:

```
if
    let dictionary = jsonData as? [String: Any],
    let results = dictionary["results"] as? [[String: Any]],
    //You need to choose one from "results"
    !results.isEmpty, case let result = results[0],
    let lexicalEntries = result["lexicalEntries"] as? [[String: Any]],
    //You need to choose one from "lexicalEntries"
    !lexicalEntries.isEmpty, case let lexicalEntry = lexicalEntries[0],
    let pronunciations = lexicalEntry["pronunciations"] as? [[String: Any]],
    //You need to choose one from "lexicalEntries"
    !pronunciations.isEmpty, case let pronunciation = pronunciations[0]
{
    //Here you can use `pronunciation` as a Dictionary containing "audioFile" and some others...
    if let audioPath = pronunciation["audioFile"] as? String {
        print(audioPath)
    }
}
```

(You can use `let result = results.first` instead of `!results.isEmpty, case let result = results[0]`, if you always use the first element for arrays. Other two lines starting from `!...isEmpty, case let...` as well.)

You need to dig into the target element from the outermost element step by step.

Comment: Perfect thank you for breaking it all down, makes more sense now, and i have the code working.

Comment: @Joby, don't forget to accept the answer if it's helpful